# unable to cast COM object of type microsoft.office.interop.outlook.applicationclass to interface type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application

Tags: vb.net, outlook

Perform a development where it is necessary for me to obtain the mail that is registered in the Outlook session in Windows. In that sense, the only thing that the user has to do is enter their windows session password to be able to log in and then go to a SharePoint and download several files. At the time of executing the programming, it sends me the following error.

> Please verify whit the support the next error: Unable to cast COM
> object type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass' to
> interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application'. This
> operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component
> for the interface with ID '{00063001-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'
> failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).

I already checked in regedit, but the subkey is at 0, I investigated this a little in other internet sites but I still have the same problem.
Can you help me to see where the error is? This is the code that I developed.

**The Outlook version is 2016 (O365) and Windows 10.**

```
Imports System.Security
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.IO

Imports Microsoft.SharePoint
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client
Imports System
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Text
Imports Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Module UpdateDB
    Dim password As String
    Dim url As String
    Dim username As String
    Dim ctx As ClientContext

    Dim securedPassword

    Public Function updateDb(value As Integer)
        Try

            ActivateOL()

            Dim outlook As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application()

            Dim addrEntry As Outlook.AddressEntry = outlook.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry

            If addrEntry.Type = "EX" Then
                Dim currentUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser = outlook.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()

                If currentUser IsNot Nothing Then
                    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
                    username = currentUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
                End If
            End If

            Dim siteUrl As String = "https://name_company.sharepoint.com/sites/test/"

            password = Form1.MyInputBox("Please Enter Your Password")


            Form1.ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
            Form1.ProgressBar1.Maximum = 28
            Form1.ProgressBar1.Visible = True
            Form1.Label115.Visible = True
            Form1.Label115.BringToFront()
            Form1.ProgressBar1.Value = 0


            url = "https://name_company.sharepoint.com/sites/test/SiteFiles/test.txt"

            ctx = New ClientContext(url)

            securedPassword = New SecureString()
            For Each c In password.ToCharArray()
                securedPassword.AppendChar(c)
            Next


            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\Temp\test.txt")
            ctx.Credentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword)
            DownloadFile(url, ctx.Credentials, "C:\Temp\test.txt")
            Form1.ProgressBar1.Value = 1
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Please verify whit the support the next error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "TEST")
            Form1.ProgressBar1.Value = 0
            Form1.ProgressBar1.Visible = False
            value = 1
            Return value
            GoTo finFunction
        End Try
        ctx.Credentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword)

        url = "https://name_company.sharepoint.com/sites/test/DATA%20BASE/DEVICES.xlsx"
        ctx = New ClientContext(url)
        ctx.Credentials = New SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securedPassword)
        DownloadFile(url, ctx.Credentials, "C:\Users\Public\Documents\TEST.xlsx")
        Form1.ProgressBar1.Value = 3


        MsgBox("UPDATED COMPLETED", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MessageBoxButtons.OK, "ABB - MNS PRO")

        Form1.ProgressBar1.Visible = False
        Form1.Label115.Visible = False
finFunction:
    End Function

    Sub DownloadFile(ByVal webUrl As String, ByVal credentials As ICredentials, ByVal fileRelativeUrl As String)
        Using client = New WebClient()
            client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f")
            client.Headers.Add("User-Agent: Other")
            client.Credentials = credentials
            client.DownloadFile(webUrl, fileRelativeUrl)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Sub DeleteFilesInsideFolder(ByVal target_folder_path As String)
        ' loop through each file in the target directory
        For Each file_path As String In Directory.GetFiles(target_folder_path)
            ' delete the file if possible...otherwise skip it
            Try
                My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(file_path)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "TEST")
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub

    <DllImport("netapi32.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Public Function NetUserChangePassword(
     <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)> ByVal OldPass As String) As Integer
    End Function

    Public Sub ChangePassword(ByVal oldPassword As String)
        Try
            NetUserChangePassword(oldPassword)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        End Try
    End Sub

    Sub ActivateOL()
        'Error 429 occurs with GetObject if Outlook is not running.
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

        If Err.Number = 429 Then 'Outlook is NOT running.
            MsgBox("Outlook is not running")
        End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

**Thanks for the support.**

**First Update**

```
    Public Function updateDb(value As Integer)
        Try

            ActivateOL()

            Dim outlook As Outlook.Application = Nothing

            Try
                outlook = DirectCast(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application"), Outlook.Application)
            Catch
                outlook = New Outlook.Application()
            End Try
    End Sub

    Sub ActivateOL()
        'Error 429 occurs with GetObject if Outlook is not running.
        Dim objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

        If Err.Number = 429 Then 'Outlook is NOT running.
            MsgBox("Outlook is not running")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You know what I'm a big fan of? When people post a big wad of code and say that it throws an exception but don't say what line it is thrown on. Nothing like spending time working out things that the OP already knows.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, thank you for your answer. The problem is that in the developed code, it works without problem, but when I run it already installed on another computer, that is when it sends that message, that is why I do not include in which line.

Comment: You mean something like: `dim outlook as Outlook.Application = nothing try outlook = directcast(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application"), Outlook.Application) catch outlook = new Outlook.Application() end try`?

Comment: As mentioned, you should post the section of code that fails, possibly in a way that can be tested. You're showing this just in a comment in the very last part of your code. + Do yourself a favor, remove all `On Error Resume Next` lines from everywhere in your code.

Comment: @Jimi, thank you for your answers. The `On Error Resume Next` lines was removed, and please, let me to to do a new test in other computer because in my computer run without problem. Whit the new code I'll give a new comment. Thank you again.

Comment: @Jimi I checked line by line and this line is the one that gives problems **`Dim objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")`**, but now appear this message **Cannot create ActiveX component**.I check the target CPU in the project and is x86.

Comment: I think I suggested to use `Marshal.GetActiveObject()` for this. -- Your Project need to target `AnyCPU` and use the `AnyCPU` profile to build, verifying that the `Prefer 32-bit` option is not selected.

Comment: @Jimi, hi and yes, was added `Marshal.GetActiveObject()` in the code, but now send the error message **Cannot create ActiveX component**, please check the first update in the `Sub ActiveOL()`, the line `Dim objOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")`

Comment: `Marshal.GetActiveObject()` is meant to replace `GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")`. If you want to create the Outlook COM only if an instance of Outlook is already created in the System, then remove `outlook = New Outlook.Application()` in the `catch` block and replace it with a MessageBox which informs that the object cannot be created. -- If the object cannot be created, there's the chance that the COM object is not `Outlook.Application`. In that case, see what that is. Since it's just a string, you can lookup the Registry and find out, then use that string to create the object.

Comment: Did you also change the target CPU and the build profile as described?

Answer (score 2):

It not seems a problem of your code but a problem on Windows-Outlook configuration matter.

I've solved using point **3 "Ensure MSOUTL.LIB is Registered"** of this fantastic guide (the most precise and techincal that I've found after 'few' hours of search)
[webmakers - Interface not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040155) – Microsoft Office/Outlook Error](https://webmakers.co.nz/interface-not-registered-exception-from-hresult-0x80040155-microsoft-office-outlook-error/), after checked the previous point, obviously.
Thanks to [Jatin-Auckland](https://it.gravatar.com/jatsptl) for a clear and step by step guide.